# Drop down option is not clickable-Selenium webdriver(ECLIPSE)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, linkedin-api, html-select, dropdown

When I tried to automate Linkedin with related to automation study research, I found that the drop down clicks are not working.

The code was:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_LANUAGEDROPDOWN"))));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Português (Portuguese)");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
```

The console is displaying:

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"name","selector":"selectLanguage"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=63.0.3239.132)

Can any one help me to find what the error is and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that selector of the Dropdown is incorrect. Selenium can't find it. Try to define a correct selector.

Comment: The selector is correct.The click on the element is not working

Answer (score 0):

If selector is correct, than you need to wait, till this element appears in DOM.